# mime_parser.php not decoding emails with attachments

Tags: php, email, pipe, attachment

I have a script that is using cpanel pipe to execute a php file whenever a mail is received. My problem is that whenever I send an email with attachments; the mime_parser.php library doesn't decode that information as well. Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
  require_once('inc/engage.php');

  // Create socket
  $sock = fopen("php://stdin", 'r');
  $email = '';
  while(!feof($sock)){
   $email .= fread($sock, 1024);
  }

  fclose($sock);

  require_once('libraries/rfc822_addresses.php');
  require_once('libraries/mime_parser.php');

  $mime = new mime_parser_class;
  $mime->ignore_syntax_errors = 1;
  $parameters = array('Data' => $email);

  $mime->Decode($parameters, $decoded);

  $DB->query("INSERT INTO email_accounts_mail (`message`) VALUES('".serialize($decoded)."')");
?>
```

rfc822_addresses.php: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/suhastech/pushmail/master/class/rfc822_addresses.php

mime_parser.php: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ryancramerdesign/EmailImage/master/pop3_classes/mime_parser.php

I want the email to decode the message with and without attachments. Now it decodes it without attachments; but not with... what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself. By saving the data in a tmp folder and deleting it after it was used, I could retrieve all data stored by the attachments. It was done by adding the SaveBody attribute in the parameters array with a specified folder (mine was tmp), and then creating the folder. After I'm done with the content within the folder I delete all files there to save up space. :-)